# Show that $\mathcal{G} := \bigcap_{\theta\in\Theta}\mathcal{F}_{\theta}$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $\{\mathcal{F}_{\theta}:\theta\in\Theta\}$ be a family of $\sigma$-algebras on $\Omega$. Show that $\mathcal{G} := \bigcap_{\theta\in\Theta}\mathcal{F}_{\theta}$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $\Omega\in\mathcal{F}_{\theta}$ for each $\theta\in\Theta$, we conclude that $\Omega\in\mathcal{G}$. Moreover, let $A\in\mathcal{G}$. Then $A\in\mathcal{F}_{\theta}$ for every $\theta\in\Theta$. Consequently, $A^{c}\in\mathcal{F}_{\theta}$ for every $\theta\in\Theta$. That is to say, $A^{c}\in\mathcal{G}$. Finally, one has that
\begin{align*}
A_{n}\in\mathcal{G},\,n\geq 1 & \Rightarrow A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}_{\theta},\,n\geq 1,\,\theta\in\Theta\\\\
& \Rightarrow \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\in\mathcal{F}_{\theta},\,\theta\in\Theta\\\\
& \Rightarrow \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\in\mathcal{G}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Is the wording of my proof correct?

Is there another way to prove? I am new to this so any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I don't think there is another proof. It is just about checking the required axioms.

Comment: Part of the learning process is gaining confidence in ourselves.

Comment: These type or arguments occur in Mathematics very often. In general, if you have a family $\{A_\theta:\theta\in\Theta\}$ such that each $A_\theta$ satisfies some property $P$ (being an $\sigma$--algebra for example, being a linear space, etc) then $\bigcap_{\theta\in\Theta}\mathcal{A}_\theta$ also satisfies property $P$ too.